# React Native Simple Image Caching

Tags: react-native

I need to cache user avatars in a React Native chat app and load them as quickly as possible.

- The built-in React Native Image can only cache iOS, so it's not a
  viable option.
- [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image) hasn't been updated for
  more than a year and has numerous issues.
- [react-native-image-cache](https://github.com/georstat/react-native-image-cache) works well but is slower when displaying the same image for the 2nd time or more compared to the built-in Image. Additionally, it is opinionated, requiring the use of animations, which gives it the appearance of being even slower.
- All the [custom caching components](https://blog.logrocket.com/caching-images-react-native-tutorial-with-examples/) I've come across were designed for Expo.

Comment: Why not use Expo?  I can no longer fathom someone deciding to use RN but not to use Expo.  The productivity and DX improvements brought to RN by Expo over the past 2 years have been incredible to watch.

Comment: this is an old 6-year-old project, expo seemed a weaker option back then

Comment: It was.  But Expo is great today.  Moving to Expo would not be hard unless you have modified the native projects (ios & android) heavily.  If the modifications can be described to someone as a set of steps, you could code those steps into a Config Plugin (if you still need those native modifications).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple component I've come up with. It's heavily based on [react-native-image-cache](https://github.com/georstat/react-native-image-cache), so most of the credit should go to the author of this library.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import { Dirs, FileSystem } from 'react-native-file-access'
import SHA1 from 'crypto-js/sha1'

type Props = {
  uri: string
  placeholder: () => JSX.Element
  style?: any
  resizeMode?: any
}

const CacheImage = ({ uri, placeholder: Placeholder, ...props }: Props) => {
  const [source, setSource] = useState<{ uri: string } | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImage = async () => {
      try {
        const cachePath = await getCachePath(uri)
        const fileExists = await FileSystem.exists(cachePath)
        if (fileExists) {
          setSource({ uri: `file://${cachePath}` })
          return
        }

        const base64data = await downloadImage(uri)
        await FileSystem.writeFile(cachePath, base64data, 'base64')
        setSource({ uri: `file://${cachePath}` })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error caching image', error)
        setSource({ uri: uri }) // set the source to the original URI if an error occurs
      }
    }

    fetchImage()
  }, [uri])

  return source ? <Image source={source} {...props} /> : <Placeholder />
}

async function getCachePath(uri: string) {
  const filename = uri.substring(
    uri.lastIndexOf('/'),
    uri.indexOf('?') === -1 ? uri.length : uri.indexOf('?')
  )

  const ext =
    filename.indexOf('.') === -1
      ? '.jpg'
      : filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.'))
  const sha = SHA1(uri)
  const cacheKey = `${sha}${ext}`
  const cacheDir = Dirs.CacheDir
  const cachePath = `${Dirs.CacheDir}/${cacheKey}`

  let dirExists = await FileSystem.exists(cacheDir)
  if (!dirExists) {
    await FileSystem.mkdir(cacheDir)
  }

  return cachePath
}

async function downloadImage(uri: string) {
  const response = await fetch(uri)
  const blob = await response.blob()
  const reader = new FileReader()
  const dataUrlPromise = new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const base64data = reader.result
      if (typeof base64data === 'string') {
        resolve(base64data.substring(base64data.indexOf(',') + 1)) // remove the `data:` scheme and the MIME type
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Failed to read blob as data URL'))
      }
    }
  })
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
  return await dataUrlPromise
}

export default CacheImage
```

This is how it works:

1. Convert the passed URI to a path using SHA1.
2. Check if the cache directory exists; otherwise, create one.
3. Verify if there is a file under that path.
4. If a file exists, return this path.
5. Otherwise, fetch the image and save it under that path.
6. Display a placeholder while steps 1-5 are in progress.
7. Most importantly, if any of steps 1-5 fail, it returns the original URI to prevent any disruptions.

I believe this provides a solid foundation, and you can further customize it based on your specific requirements.